# Redirect to a custom error page on razor macro error

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, umbraco

In Umbraco, if there is a razor macro on a page, and that razor macro throws an exception, the page is still displayed, but it shows "Error loading macro xyz.cshtml" where the macro would have been.

I'd like to redirect to a custom/friendly error page whenever that happens, but I can't find any information on how to do it.  Is it possible?

I've tried setting the `<customErrors>` tag as usual, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within each razor script, you could surround your code with a try/catch and then redirect if an error is caught:

```
@try
{
    //macro code...
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //possible code to log error...

    //redirect to friendly error page:
    Response.Redirect("~/path-to-error-page/");
}
```

But rather than redirecting the user, you could also just catch the error and then do nothing. It depends on your needs.

Comment: That would probably work, but I'd prefer not to clutter my macros with try-catch blocks.  Anyways, thanks for the response - I may end up doing it that way.

Comment: See [this forum post](http://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/razor/25449-Hide-uncaught-exceptions-in-razor-macros) for a few more suggestions.